# Virtual Machine add increased disk space as new partition ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning

I work inside a VM which runs ubuntu. As I was running out of space, I asked my System Admin to increase the space of the VM which he did and asked me to add the increased space as a new partition.

Here is the output of `lsblk` command listing the drives. `vda` has around 390G of unused space:

[image]

Below is the output from the `fdisk -l` (somehow the start and end cylinder information seem all messed up. There are in total 63741 cylinders and still the start and end figures in the partition is much larger that that) :

[image]

**Query:** How can I claim the newly added space in `vda` as a new partition ?

PS: I would need a command-line solution as I don't have access to GUI.

Comment: You need the partition editor `parted`. You can create `vda3`, or you can move `vda2` to the end of the disc (turning swap off while you do so, of course) and extend `vda1` to fill the intervening space.

Comment: @AFH Thanks for the response. If I can expand vda1 to fill the intervening space, without loosing my current data, then that would be great. Can you please outline how I can do that? Or maybe point me to a post ?

Comment: @AFH: I am also not sure how to "cut out" the unused space. I suppose using command line one does it using cylinder number. But if you look at my fdisk output, the cylinder start and end doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: I've always used the GUI front-end `gparted`, which makes life very simple, so I'll need to check the manual to see what commands it would produce. If it's complicated, I'll need to do it as an answer, once I'm clear on what you need. The `fdisk` output is slightly odd: when I run it on my Ubuntu 15.04, everything is reported in 512-byte sectors, but your listing shows (1KB) blocks instead of sectors - if you double these numbers, then they correspond to the start and end figures.

Comment: I can't see the `parted` command for moving a partition, but after swapping has been turned off it is probably easier and certainly quicker to delete and recreate: you will need a calculator to work out where it has to start and end (note `fdisk` reports end as the final sector, while `parted` reports start + size, one higher). Or remove the swap partition altogether and use a swap file instead. After sorting the swap, you simply use the `resizepart` command to move the end of `/dev/vda1'. I suggest you specify `unit Mib` to make `print` list sizes to use in other commands.